# Getting the disk volume number by the volume label through batch programming

Tags: windows, batch

I want to create a script to automatically mount a drive in windows by specifying its volume label only. The idea is to provide the label and get back the volume number and use it into diskpart through a script.

Using ChatGPT I was able to get somewhere but can't say I was able to fully follow because I do not have much experience with batch programming. It could also be that the answer might have not been the best.

ChatGPT suggested:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType=3" get VolumeName /value') do (
  set disklabel=%%i
  echo Found disk label: %disklabel%
  diskpart /s script.txt
)
```

And the script (separate file) was

```
select volume <disk label>
assign letter=<drive letter>
```

Assuming that "Super Drive" is the label of the drive, how can I make it work just by double clicking the bat file? By the way, I am familiar that diskpart needs a separate script to automate it (script.txt) but I am not sure how to write

```
<disk label> 
<disk letter>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in =;('
     wmic.exe logicaldisk where "DriveType=3" get VolumeName^,Caption /format:xml ^| find "/VALUE"
   ')do if "!_Caption!" == "" (set "_Caption=%%~i")else set "_DiskLabel=%%~i" && echo\ Found: !_DiskLabel!

if /i "Super Drive" == "!_DiskLabel!" >"%temp%\%~n0.txt" =;(
      echo\ Select volume !_DiskLabel! 
      echo\ Assign letter=!_Caption! 
     );=

findstr "S A" <"%temp%\%~n0.txt" && 2>nul =;(
     diskpart.exe /s "%temp%\%~n0.txt"
     timeout 3 | del "%temp%\%~n0.txt" 
    );= 

endlocal
```